# How to create a li tag dynamically using selenium webdriver on java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is my ol tag

```
<ol>
<li class="dd-item" ><div class="dd-handle"><img alt="testing" src="test2.png" s><a  name="tree" style="margin:5px;">page1</a></div></li>
<li class="dd-item" ><div class="dd-handle"><img alt="testing" src="test2.png" s><a  name="tree" style="margin:5px;">page2</a></div></li>
</ol>
```

I want to insert this below tag to above ol tag as 3rd element using selenium webdriver in java

```
<li class="dd-item" ><div class="dd-handle"><img alt="testing" src="test2.png" s><a  name="tree" style="margin:5px;">page3</a></div></li>
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver is designed for browser automation, not for changing server side code or HTML returned by the server. However, if you want to change the HTML temporarily on the client side, you'll have to do what everyone else does and run some JavaScript on the browser.

As the [Selenium FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?) states, you can execute JavaScript with a `WebDriver` instance by casting it into a `JavascriptExecutor`:

```java
WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return document.title");
```

Then you can use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM inside the page being shown on the browser that your `WebDriver` instance is currently driving.

Comment: I want to create element with class and then do drag source to the newly created element. How to do it?

Comment: Could you share some light on what's exactly your goal here? You want to test whether a user can break your page by adding things on their own?