# Specflow selenium webdriver, drag and drop not working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I tried to implement drag and drop functionality of html elements with all following ways. But none of them work for me.
This is .net framework project with latest specflow version.

**1 way**

```
var actions = new Actions(Context.WebDriver);
 actions.DragAndDrop(elementDrag, destination).Release(elementDrag).Build().Perform();
```

**2 way**

```
actions.MoveToElement(elementDrag, 10, 10, MoveToElementOffsetOrigin.Center)
.ClickAndHold(elementDrag)
   .MoveByOffset(5, 5)
   .MoveToElement(destination)
   .Release(elementDrag)
   .Build()
   .Perform();
```

**3 way**

```
  actions.MoveToElement(elementDrag, 10, 10, MoveToElementOffsetOrigin.Center)
    .ClickAndHold()
    .MoveByOffset(50, -300)
    .Release(elementDrag)
    .Build()
    .Perform();
```

**4 way**

```
 actions.ClickAndHold(elementDrag).Build().Perform();
 Thread.Sleep(3000);
 actions.MoveToElement(destination).Build().Perform();
 actions.Release(destination).Build().Perform();
```

And I sow that drag and drop is a known issue of selenium and it can solve by using javasript implementation. No idea what that is.

Can anyone suggest me a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript workaround for drag and drop in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384710/javascript-workaround-for-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @GregBurghardt I tried these both way. JavaScript functions are executing. But dragging  and dropping does not work.

Comment: Which browser, browser version, web driver and web driver version are you using?

Comment: Chrome browser latest version, Specflow latest version, Chrome driver latest version. It's a.net framework project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this version.

Identify the source and destination.

```
var ele1 = Browser.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='myDragableItem")); 
var ele2 = Browser.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='myDestination"));


DragAndDrop(ele1, ele2);



        public static void DragAndDrop(IWebElement element1, IWebElement element2)
    {
        WaitForElementEnabled(element1);
        WaitForElementEnabled(element2);
        var builder = new Actions(driver);
        var dragAndDrop = builder.ClickAndHold(element1).MoveToElement(element2).Release(element1).Build();
        dragAndDrop.Perform();
    }

    public static void WaitForElementEnabled(IWebElement element)
    {
        try { _wait.Until(webDriver => element.Enabled); }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { if (!WaitForNotFoundElement_Enabled(element)) throw; } }
    }
```

Comment: What is the body of WaitForElementEnabled method ?

Comment: You just need to identify the source and destination and just pass the values. I have this working on several solutions in C#. You may need to play with the destination path to get it right if it is not obvious.

Comment: My Source and destination has loaded when I do the dragging. Tried this code but does not work for me.

Comment: Is your site public that we can have access? Typically the reason this does not work is specific elements have to be source and destination. Since none of these examples work for you, it would seem that the issue is possibly what you are using?

Comment: Janith - I read that HTML5  is causing some woes with Drag and Drop. I found this which may help - https://www.testautomatisierung.org/drag-drop-fuer-html-5-elemente-mit-selenium/

Comment: Now giving javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document

Comment: your last comment helped me to fix the issue

Comment: What is the variable _wait?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JavaScriptExecutor

```
IWebElement source= driver.FindElement(By.Id(selector));
IWebElement destination= driver.FindElement(By.Id(selector));
string java_script =
       "var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEffe" +
       "ct:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:[],items:{},types:[],setData:fun" +
       "ction(format,data){this.items[format]=data;this.types.push(for" +
       "mat);},getData:function(format){return this.items[format];},clea" +
       "rData:function(format){}};var emit=function(event,target){var ev" +
       "t=document.createEvent('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,false);" +
       "evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);};emit('" +
       "dragstart',src);emit('dragenter',tgt);emit('dragover',tgt);emit(" +
       "'drop',tgt);emit('dragend',src);";
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript(java_script, source, destination);
```

Comment: Are you using XPath for the selector ?.If yes then please replace FindElement(By.Id(selector)) with FindElement(By.Xpath(selector)) and have a try.